# Maven error: package does not exist

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am able build my java project on my local machine, it builds successfully using maven. However, when I build it on a Jenkins machine, i get a compile error:

> package **javax.jms** does not exist

What does this mean? Where is it looking for **javax.jms**? In local m2 repo, classpath?

I had to make the following changes to my pom.xml to get it to work on Linux:

a) Explicitly stated maven-site-plugin version to 2.1.
       
                org.apache.maven.plugins
                maven-site-plugin
                2.1

b) Changed maven-surefire-plugin version from 2.4.3 to 2.18.1
                maven-surefire-plugin
                2.18.1

c) Added the following dependencies :

```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
       <version>1.4</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xx.yyy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xx.yyy</groupId>
            <artifactId>orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.5</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
```

Why do I have to change the pom.xml on Linux. The build works on my Windows 7 machine without changing the pom.xml.

Comment: Can you put the goals you are using for building with Maven? And also what dependencies are you using for javax.jms?

Comment: Generally, when you build locally, Maven will pull down the required dependencies from the Internet. For a more official build in, say, a corporate environment, the dependencies will be pulled from a standard internal maven repo. It might just be a matter of adding the dependency to that repo.

Comment: You might also look into Maven's settings.xml configuration file on the Jenkins box to see about repository locations. See http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Answer (score 1):

First, try to check if you have correct dependency for Maven to get `javax.jms` packages. You can try `Apache Geronimo` dependency or `JavaEE API`. (Reference :[What is the right Maven dependency for javax.jms.* classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334323/what-is-the-right-maven-dependency-for-javax-jms-classes))

For `Apache Geronimo`

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

For `JavaEE API`

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also, make sure you are building your application on `Jenkins` with the following goals:

```
mvn clean install
```

After you build your application with `Maven` on `Jenkins` machine, the package should appear in local `m2 repo` for `Jenkins`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The javax.jms resides on my local repository on the Jenkins box. Why is it not picking it up? Can i debug the maven command to see where it is looking?

Comment: Yes, you can check your dependency tree with this command http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: On my local windows machine, the maven build worked fine. On  Jenkins Linux, I had to update the pom.xml(add additional dependencies); this updated the classpath, including the javax.jms jar. This fixed the compile/build error. Why does it work on my local windows machine, why did I have to update the pom.xml on Linux to  the add the necessary jars to classpath? Is it a potential firewall issue on the Linux machine?

Comment: No, this should not be the firewall and I don't see the reason you need to change your dependencies, jars or pom.xml depending on OS. Could you post what you have changed in pom.xml and which jars did you added/excluded?

Comment: I have updated the question with the changes in the pom.