# Gradle javax.jms dependency not getting downloaded

Tags: java, gradle, activemq-classic, build.gradle

I am trying to build a JMS (activeMq) based application using gradle. I need the javax.jms api dependency to be downloaded.
I add this to my compile time dependency:

```
dependencies{
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-jms:'+deps.springVersion,
        'org.springframework:spring-messaging:'+deps.springVersion,
        'javax.jms:jms:1.1'     

    }
```

Upon gradle build, it says that the jar cannot be downloaded. When I navigate to the maven Central and click on download jar, the jar is not present, so I guess that's why the jar is not getting downloaded by gradle. How can I include this dependency in gradle ? is there a way out ?

Comment: Yep, that jar is not in Maven Central that's why you can't get it. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6336137/3248346

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there's [no](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.jms%7Cjms%7C1.1%7Cjar) jar file, only pom. As can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334323/what-is-the-right-maven-dependency-for-javax-jms-classes) [this](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22geronimo-jms_1.1_spec%22) is the dependency You're looking for.

Your dependencies block will be:

```
dependencies{
   compile 'org.springframework:spring-jms:'+deps.springVersion,
   'org.springframework:spring-messaging:'+deps.springVersion,
   'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:1.1.1'
}
```