# Java Message Queue Abstraction

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, amqp

I'm fairly new to Java and am currently writing a web application using a number of Dropwizard based micro services and Java8 SE. I now want to integrate a Message Queue for Async communication between the services and want to start by using a cloud based queue like Amazon SQS. However I don't want to lock myself into a particular cloud provider so would like the option of easily switching to another provider or using something like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ later on. So my question is, is there a framework in Java that allows this? For example with Hibernate I can switch between databases with a simple config change, is there an equivalent for Message queues?

I've spent quite a bit of time researching this but haven't been able to find a definitive answer anywhere, so far I've found;

- **JMS**, Which looks a bit like what I'm after but looks to only be available in the Java EE edition and may require and app server? Is that correct?
- **AMQP**, Which looks like a low level protocol for message queue interoperability. There is also Apache Qpid Proton which looks like a pure AMQP message library but all the documentation and examples for Java seem to use the JMS.
- All the tutorials I can find for specific MQs (Rabbit, etc) use those Queues specific client libraries.
- Obviously I could add my own abstraction layer but don't want to re-invent the wheel and I suspect I'm not the first developer to want to do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Hibernate or just JDBC for that matter allows you to switch amongst differing Database providers the JMS API allows you to switch amongst message Brokers or message Providers at will without breaking you code provided you are not using any specific vendor extensions in your code.

JMS is just an API, there is no JMS protocol only the API that various vendors implement and provide you a client to use with their messaging provider.  You can use the JMS API from your Java 8 code just fine, you just need to pull in the JMS API jar using whatever build management tool you happen to have chosen along with the client jar from the vendor you happen to be using at that time.  To see how to grab an Apache licensed version of the JMS API jar see the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334323/what-is-the-right-maven-dependency-for-javax-jms-classes).

From what I can see Amazon does offer a JMS implementation, the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/jmsclient.html) seems to cover it well.

When or if you decide to switch to another messaging product such as ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ there are JMS implementations offered by each that allow you to swap out the client and not need to change any existing code (again provided you aren't using any vendor extensions).  If you switch to a messaging solutiuon that offers AMQP 1.0 support than there is a JMS over AMQP 1.0 implementation offered by the Apache Qpid project [here](http://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html).

I think you need to spend some time reading up on the JMS specification and some tutorials to get a handle on what JMS is and how leveraging JMS and JNDI you can create provider agnostic code.

Answer (score 1):

JMS in the java world is one of the most common API for producing/consumming messages over queues. When using JMS you are free to use any JMS provider (activeMQ, rabbitMQ ...), and if do not make any direct call to your provider (only calling the JMS API) you can switch from one to another easily.

In order for the message to travel from a producer tu a consumer you need a broker ( a software that will handle them). Brokers can be hosted on a dedicated servers or embbeded in your application (I would not recommend the second option).

AMQP is a more recent protocol and is wire-level. Some Brokers are able to handle both AMQP and JMS.

Both AMQP and JMS can provide you with decent abstraction. However they both have their limits. On one hand with JMS you may be tempted to use some feature/fine configuration tuning, and then you may become implementation-depend due to a specific set of behaviors. On the other hand with AMPQ given the AMQP version you've choosen (0.9 or 1.0+), you only may be able to select only a few  broker because those versions differs heavily and at the moment most broker only supports one of them.

Comment: Thanks for this, so is the JMS only available in Java EE? Is there any away to use it in Java SE. My problem is the Java EE is only available for Java 7 and I've already used a lot of Java 8 features in my code, so switching back to Java 7 will involve a lot of re-factoring!

Comment: Sure you can use it with java SE, just include the needed jars such as javax.jms in your project path. You can do it directly or with tools like maven.

Answer (score 0):

Check your provider carefully if you're looking for JMS 2.0, some - i.e., ActiveMQ - only support JMS 1.1.