# Spring boot with tibco jms listener

Tags: spring-jms, tibco

I am trying to listen Tibco ems queue (wants annotation based configuration) from SpringBoot.  I don't see any example which described how to configure and listen Tibco ems queue from SpringBoot.

Any lead or example on this ?

Answer (score 6):

Create a connection factory in the spring boot application class

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){

    TibjmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory(JMS_URL); 
    connectionFactory.setUserName(USERNAME);
    connectionFactory.setUserPassword(PASSWORD);

    return connectionFactory;
}
```

For sending message , use the send() of JmsMessagingTemplate .

The listener class should have an annotated method which has to be invoked for processing the message received from queue.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "queue_name")
public void receiveMessage(Message<T> message) {
   //Any processing to be done here
}
```

Comment: Nice response but I have surprising question - where to find ConnectionFactory interface? I have TibjmsConnectionFactory inside com.tibco.ems:tibjms JAR version 8.2, but I dont have javax.jms.ConnectionFactory...

Comment: @kabeen I got the interface from geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar already present in my classpath. There is another discussion on similar lines. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334323/what-is-the-right-maven-dependency-for-javax-jms-classes

Comment: Can any one please post whole project structure of JMS tibco using spring boot.as I am new in spring boot .I don't understand how to add JMS tibco